# Eclipse - When executing TestNG test don't open results tab automatically

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, testng

Sometimes when I execute TestNG Test(s) in Eclipse

And I need **only to check the console** tab for logs

But when the test ends, it automatically move to Results tab

I want to remain in current/console tab,

Can I execute TestNG without moving automatically to Results tab?

**EDIT**

As @nitind comment, it's not happening in JUnit test

Comment: What "Results" tab are you referring to?

Comment: @nitnd https://testng.org/doc/eclipse.html#eclipse-viewing

Comment: Removing the JUnit tag.